# jQuery closest() not selecting class added dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the [following jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WFawp/) which has a `.tab` class (on a span) that is supposed to remove/replace the open (or close) class on the `.container` onclick -- and although my console logs are showing that successfully, using `closest()` I'm not able to grab the specific class in question to change/toggle that class.

I've tried quite a few variations, but am not sure if I am selecting this wrong.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.closest actually works it's way outwards so a better option would be

```
$(this).find('.panel .close').removeClass('close').addClass('open');
```